# How to make a script kill itself after running after a specific time?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, kill, kill-process

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Start: " $(date +%s)
(time hive --hiveconf mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=0.5 --hiveconf mapred.reduce.tasks=10 --hiveconf mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies=15 --hiveconf hive.execution.engine=mr -f sample-queries-tpcds/query50.sql --database tpcds_text_db_1_10) 2> output/tpcds_query_2c_50_mr.out
echo "End: " $(date +%s)
```

How can I add some code inside it so that it will kill itself say after 5 seconds of execution? (like after 5 seconds of ./script.sh )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `hive` in the background, then go to sleep for 5 seconds and kill `hive` when `sleep` exits. If `hive` has already completed, `kill` will print an error message, but you can redirect it to `/dev/null` to ignore it.

```
hive --hiveconf mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=0.5 \
     --hiveconf mapred.reduce.tasks=10 \
     --hiveconf mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies=15 \
     --hiveconf hive.execution.engine=mr \
     -f sample-queries-tpcds/query50.sql \
     --database tpcds_text_db_1_10) \
     2> output/tpcds_query_2c_50_mr.out & hive_pid=$!

sleep 5 & wait
kill $hive_pid 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

This script will kill itself after 5 seconds:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Start: " $(date +%s)
sleep 5s && kill $$ &
while sleep 1; do echo Working; done
echo "End: " $(date +%s)
```

The pipeline `sleep 5s && kill $$` is run in the background and issues a kill after 5 seconds.

Your command, which could be `hive`, runs in the foreground.  In the example above, I used a while-loop because it allows easy demonstration that the concept works.  Substituting in your hive command results in:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Start: " $(date +%s)
sleep 5s && kill $$ &
(time hive --hiveconf mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps=0.5 --hiveconf mapred.reduce.tasks=10 --hiveconf mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies=15 --hiveconf hive.execution.engine=mr -f sample-queries-tpcds/query50.sql --database tpcds_text_db_1_10) 2> output/tpcds_query_2c_50_mr.out
echo "End: " $(date +%s)
```

Comment: adding on to add, how can I run a specific command (task) after say 5 seconds?

Comment: @MonaJalal Just replace `kill $$` with whatever command you want to run.  Or, do you want to both kill and run a command?  If so, in what order?